# How can I implement a multi dimensional array or array of records in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, records

I've learned the theory in a computer science class about multi dimensional arrays & records of arrays but I am unsure of how to implement this in Python. I was thinking of using an array of records as it would allow me to have different data types in the one record but at the same time I was thinking that a multi dimensional array would also be good to learn in Python.

I've Googled around a bit & I have found numpy but I'm not sure which function in numpy I'd use. I saw one with tuples but I wasn't keen on using that as tuples can't be modified.

I'm using Python 3.2 but I don't mind using Python 2.7 either.

Comment: By array of records you mean array of classes i presume.

Comment: @aquavitae I'm just wondering if there's another option besides using a list. I'm trying to learn new things.

Comment: @jamylak I haven't touched on classes yet.

Comment: @AnonUser well if you mean records like in Pascal for example, in Python you would use a class, but using a list would be much more simple.

Comment: @jamylak Python is the only language I know how to program in so I'm not quite sure what you're saying but thank you for helping anyway.

Comment: @AnonUser Oh right that's ok. When you said array of records i immediately thought it was Pascal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends how you want to interact with them. Consider using [Numpy](https://numpy.org/). Specifically, have a look at the [N-Dimensional array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html). It provides a rich API for manipulation and comparison.

If numpy feels like overkill, you can implement a multi-array using simple tuples/lists.

```
multi_array = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
]

>>> multi_array[0][0]
>>> multi_array[1][4]
```

As an example, to convert `multi_array` into a numpy `ndarray`:

```
import numpy as np
np.ndarray((2, 5), buffer=np.array(multi_array), dtype=int)
```

Notice that ndarray expects as it's first argument a `shape`. This means you need to know the dimensions of the array before you create it. Changing the dimensions of the ndarray is known as 'reshaping'.

Comment: +1 for Numpy. With *multidimensional* arrays of regular dimensions Numpy is not an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you mean by "records" but you could use a list of lists to represent a two dimensional array. read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) to find out more.